# How can I display an array of 17,272 characters on one line

Tags: arrays, console-application, output

Thank you for your interest in my question, I cannot seem to find a remedy for this problem. I am trying to display an array of 17,272 characters horizontally (in the same line) in console application and I tried some of the solutions that were mentioned in stackoverflow like using `console.write` instead of `control.writleine` and adding `string.join` but the result is not what I want but close to what I want, I say close because the output of the 17,272 characters break into the next line at the end of the window. I would appreciate to know whether this is even possible. My code is below. thank you.

```
for (int i = 0; i < genome1.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write(string.Join(" Genome 1= {0}", genome1[i]));
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you can set the width of the console that wide, and I'm extremely sure there would never be a need to do so that wouldn't make your users totally irate with you. I know I'd be extremely pi&&ed off if I had to scroll a console window horizontally that far. (What you're observing is not "breaking"; it's "wrapping", where the buffer isn't wide enough so it wraps around to the start of the next line.)

Comment: @user3053274 So you gonna write outside of window or what? And when it hits display border..?